# Create accounts only for real people

Tags: session, cookies, web-crawler

I am building a simple website where users can try a website without registering. I basically create *shadow* account and log users in without them knowing, so I don't have to bother with functionality of not-logged in users.

I then set the cookie to a user so they can come and use website anytime later without loosing any data.

The problem is that there is lots of scrappers, bots, crawlers... These bots are unintentionally creating a new account every time they visit, because they are not accepting a cookie and I cannot identify them on 2nd visit. And some of them are visiting frequently so I end up with 10's of thousands of accounts that are never really used.

Few things came to my mind:

1. Expire/remove user if there is no further action on the page *(Seems like best idea)*
2. Detect if user accept cookies *(this requires that I redirect a user and validate that he can accept cookies - not sure how efficient/slow this is)*
3. Parse user-agent and identify the browser if unidentifiable it is a bot *(I'm not sure how reliable this is)*

What are my options to address this issue, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your user accepts cookies via AJAX. On landing page set a cookie and then send a request back to server immediately after page load with the cookie. And only if the cookie is present, then create your user. This will be quick and confirms that the users browser supports cookies.

Expire/remove user can also work well, but you might end up creating and deleting a lot of users which can be expensive on the server.

Sending a dummy User-agent header is a very simple thing for bots and I think they do it anyway (Bad bots) to make sure web servers allow crawling. So they cannot promise the authenticity of the browser.